# Как в jquery отловить событие Ctrl + стрелочка влево/вправо?

Tags: jquery

Как в jquery отловить событие "нажата клавиша Ctrl и одновременно стрелочка влево/вправо"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#selector').keydown(function(event) {
  if ( event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 37 ) { 
     //влево
  }
  if ( event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 39 ) { 
     //вправо
  }
}
```